# How to Run Appium Server and Android Emulator in Parallel through Shell Script in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, android-emulator, appium

I want to start Appium server for automated testing in Jenkins and start Emulator through commandline. When I start Appium through Appium start script in shell command in `jenkins build step`, Appium server initiates and run correctly.

But, the problem is I need to Initiate the Android Emulator by using same shell script. Since Appium server runs in background the next shell command to initiate the emulator does not affect and the jenkins build fails. So I need to run Appium server and Android Emulator in parallel through Shell Script in `Jenkins build step`.

Please provide solution to run both the scripts in parallel.

Comment: Sorry for my poor English and Thanks for your edit @RejeeshChandran

Comment: it's totally fine, we learn by making mistakes too 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made the Appium server and Android Emulator to run parallely through shell script in Jenkins build step.

I execute the following in Shell script and succesfully run my automation test.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Start Emulator and Appium:
 emulator -avd Test -noaudio -no-boot-anim -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window &
 appium &
 sleep 2m
```

The sleep command made the command to sleep or wait for the initialisation of emulator and appium server detects the device parallely.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `parallel`, like for instance:

```
node{
     stage('Tests') {
        parallel(appium: {
            //first script
        }, emulator: {
            //second script
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: @Antro make sense?

Comment: Sorry I can't understand how to execute this, But I found Solution for my Issue myself. Thanks for Your answer.